# Selenium python3/ How to find element using selenium?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

`<div class="font-weight-bold text-5xl mb-0" data-target="points.balance">170</div>`

I have a part of this code and I need to use selenium to find 170, and each time the code is executed, the selenium printed the updated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
e = driver.find_element_by_class_name("font-weight-bold.text-5xl.mb-0")
print(e.text)
```